# FTP fails on different server

Tags: php, ftp

I have a working code for images upload, it works fine my the staging server, but when deployed to live, gives "Unable to transfer via FTP", please check the code

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tempImage']['tmp_name'], $upload_to_temp)) {
            $ftp_path = "employeeimages/" . $filename;
            $ftphost = FTPDOMAIN;
            $ftpusr = FTPUSER;
            $ftppwd = FTPPASSWORD;
            if (file_exists($upload_to_temp)) {
                $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftphost) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftphost");
                $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpusr, $ftppwd);
                if (ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $upload_to_temp, FTP_BINARY)) {
                    unlink($upload_to_temp);
                    $image_up = $ftp_path;

                    mysql_query("UPDATE employees SET image = '".$ftp_path."' WHERE id = '".$newid."'");
               //     $_SESSION['emp_image'] = $ftp_path;
                }else{
                    echo "Error transferring file via ftp!<br/>";
                    echo $filename . "<br/>";
                    echo $upload_to_temp . "<br/>";
                    echo $ftp_path . "<br/>";
                }
            }else{
                echo "File does not exist in img/temp!";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Error moving file to temp location!<br>";

        }
```

Can you make a guess ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't even see the string "Unable to transfer via FTP" in your code. Where does that come from?

Comment: sorry, it was Error transferring file via ftp

Comment: What does `var_dump($login_result);` display?

Comment: Also, make sure that the values for `$ftpusr`, and `$ftppwd` match what is on the other server.

Comment: @Mike seems it has to do something with passive mode, still not sure

Comment: http://www.php.net/ftp_pasv

Answer (score 0):

When an `ftp_*()` function fails it usually generates warning messages, and I have to assume that you've set `error_reporting` to not display them. I suggest at least temporarily wrapping your if/else block like below that you can diagnose the error:

```
$prev = error_reporting(E_ALL); // turn on all error reporting levels
if( ftp_put(...) ) {

} else {

}
error_reporting($prev); // revert to previous error reporting level
```

Alternatively, PHP may be logging these errors in the apache or system logs, or you may wish to implment your own error reporting function using [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to capture this information.